# Python-How to update an entity in apeengine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

In appengine documentation, it says that the put() method replaces the previous entity. But when I do so it always adds a new entity to the datastore. How do I update an entity?

Answer (score 4):

If you call `.put()` on an entity that you've previously retrieved from the datastore, it will update the existing entity. (Make sure you're not specifying a new key for the entity.)